# How to filter an array of dictionary(Datewise) using NSPredicate in swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, filter, nspredicate

I am new to the swift, please someone help me. I have to do filter my data datewise.  This is my JSON data.

```
result =     (
                {
            Request = "sample task";
            "Requested_by" = 112;
            Source = "default-image.jpg";
            "created_at" = "2018-07-02 12:44:20";
            id = 556;
            taskId = 821;
        },
                {
            Request = cvv;
            "Requested_by" = 112;
            Source = "default-image.jpg";
            "created_at" = "2018-07-03 17:01:14";
            id = 554;
            taskId = 812;
        }
)
```

And I tried some code:

```
func filterDatesFromMainData(){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "created_at = %@", self.datetextField.text!)
    self.filterArray = NSMutableArray(array: self.dataArray.filtered(using: predicate))
    print("data: \(self.filterArray)")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In predicate variable, I will get the date from date picker. In  self.filterArray i am getting 0 elements.
Please someone help me, how to solve this task

Comment: May be your date formats not matching each other. Check what is the value in self.datetextField.text.

Comment: @appu : Swift 4 introduced filter API to filter dictionaries take a look at https://www.raywenderlich.com/163857/whats-new-swift-4

Comment: I am sending this formate 2018-07-03

Comment: see this one for e.g : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/7/examples-of-using-nspredicate-to-filter-nsfetchrequest

Comment: Then you have to remove all time part from "created_at" from your result json.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik but in my case predicate is coming like this  created_at == "2018-07-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "created_at contains[c] %@", self.datetextField.text! )
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your format is not matching with date created_at.

And

Try by replacing

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "created_at = %@", self.datetextField.text!)
```

To

```
let predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "created_at contains[c] %@", self.datetextField.text! )
```

Comment: thanks.  When i print the predicate, This value is coming. created_at == "2018-07-02"

Comment: Then you have to remove all time part from "created_at" from your result json.

Comment: Hey i have changed the answer. Can you try it?